# view with IEnumerable of object type in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. While working with MVC4 application. I am getting following errors in view(see screenshot for details). I have following code in controller action method.

```
public ActionResult ShowData()
{
      IEnumerable<object> data = AccountMaster.GetAccountsInfo(); ;
      return View(data);
}
```

and in my view

```
@Model IEnumerable<dynamic>
@{
       ViewBag.Title = "ShowData";
       WebGrid grid=new WebGrid(Model);
}

<h2>ShowData</h2>
```

[image: View Error]

as you can see I am getting this error in view. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: can you show ``GetAccountsInfo`` definition??

Comment: GetAccountsInfo method returns a IEnumerabe<object>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write `@Model` in small case `@model`

`@model IEnumerable<dynamic>`

I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please tell me the reason for it?

Comment: Because it (@model) is a predefined keyword in Razor syntax. And Model is a predefined property which is used to access the model class attributes.