# group by using linq c# on entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I need to group by Names and to sum all the instance of the name
this is my code in the controller:

```
public class FansController : Controller
{
    private dbFan db = new dbFan();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var group = from f in db.fans
                    group f by f.TimeInClub;

        return View(group);
    }
}
```

this is my code in the model:

```
public class Fans
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Gender")]
    public string MaleFemale { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("BirthDay")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Years in Club")]
    public string TimeInClub { get; set; }
}
```

and the output that I need is db that contains 2 columns: Name and Number of instance

In the view I'm using `@model IEnumeruble`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = from f in db.fans
             group 1 by f.Name into g
             select new { Name = g.Key, Amount = g.Count() };
```

Now the `@model` should currently be:

- `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. From: [view with IEnumerable of object type in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25611020/6400526): `@model IEnumerable<dynamic>`
- or that you create a class containing the two properties.

Comment: how can i do IEnumeruble<dynamic> ?

Comment: @user7024226 - updated :) see `()` in the explanations

Comment: Gilad The Teacher :)

Comment: I know. Just wanted to say Hi along with the tick :)

Comment: @user7024226 - saw now comments in answer below - Can you explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

see this

[Selecting count in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047942/selecting-count-in-linq)

And try something like:

```
var group = (from f in db.fans
            group f by a.Name into g
            select new { Name = g.Name, Count = g.Count() });
```

Comment: i created class in model called GroupInstanceByName that contain the fields Name and Amount and ID im using this code             <code>        public ActionResult GroupByName()
        {
            var result = from f in db.fans
                         group 1 by f.Name into g
                         select new GroupInstanceByName { Name = g.Key, Amount = g.Count() };

            return View(result);
        } </code> and while debugging is not looks good and makes a error

Comment: i created class in model called GroupInstanceByName that contain the fields Name and Amount and ID im using this code " public ActionResult GroupByName() { var result = from f in db.fans group 1 by f.Name into g select new GroupInstanceByName { Name = g.Key, Amount = g.Count() }; return View(result); } " and while debugging is not looks good and makes a error