# linq selectmany flatten multiple levels

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following relation (for example)

A contains one or more B's

Each B contains one or more C's and D's

I want to flatten everything using SelectMany along with some search conditions and get A,B,C and D's . This is what i have.

```
context.A.Where(a => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || a.Name.Contains(name)))
    .SelectMany(ab =>ab.b.Where(n=>n.bname.Contains(name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)),     
    (aa, bb) => new { aa, bb })   //gets all a's and b's
    .SelectMany(bc => bb.c.Where(w => w.KEYWORD.Contains(Keyword) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Keyword)),
    (bc,words) => new {bc,kwords})  //gets all b's and c's
```

Is what i am doing right? If so , then how to get B along with all D's adding to the above expression?

Comment: I would suggest you using query syntax in such scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreeing with what Ivan suggested you can flatten this 3 levels deep structure like this:

```
var query = (from a in A
             from b in (List<dynamic>)a.b
             from c in (List<dynamic>)b.c
             from d in (List<dynamic>)b.d
             select new { a, b, c, d });

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    query = query.Where(record => record.b.bname.Contains(name));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
{
    query = query.Where(record => record.c.keyword.Contains(keyword));
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

*You can also add the `where` clauses in the query at the top but seeing that you are checking if you got any valid input at all I'd put it after*

Tested it with this sample data:

```
List<dynamic> A = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { b = new List<dynamic> { new { bname = "a", c = new List<dynamic> { new { keyword = "b" } }, d = new List<dynamic> { 1, 2, 3 } } } },
    new { b = new List<dynamic> { new { bname = "a", c = new List<dynamic> { new { keyword = "d" } }, d = new List<dynamic> { 1, 2, 3 } } } }
};

string name = "a";
string keyword = "b";
```

Comment: My level is not 4 levels deep...A->B->C and D How should i restructure your query then ?

Comment: example.. Team(A) consists of TeamMembers(B). Each TeamMember(B) can have multiple skills(C) and be associated with multiple projects(D)

Comment: Your query seems to be way simpler than using lambda..let me try this Thanks!

Comment: @cableload - Let me know how it goes :) BTW for next time, it will be simpler and attract more people to help you if you explain the structure and give some sample data (like the test data I've added at the end of the question)

Comment: I do have another quick question..if i have another table call V whose structure is (id,value) and is related to relation d.id , how will i add that to the above query ? (obviously i need to join D and V)

Comment: @cableload - just add a join before the `select` :) Check SO linq documentation on joins - it is short and good

Comment: how do i show the resulting anonymous type new {a,b,c,d} into a viewmodel ? What type should that viewmodel be?

Comment: @cableload - This is a followup question and I should not be answering it as part of this question.. There are questions to this. I have answered such a question in the last couple of days. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40138355/6400526) or many other questions :)

Comment: I agree. this is a bit more complicated than i had imagined. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

**Data Selection using Lambda Syntax:**

```
var flatData = context.A.SelectMany(a => a.B.SelectMany(b => b.Select(new {a,b,c = b.C,d = b.D})
```

Going further, following checks shall be done before applying the `Where` Clause, as they check the constant input supplied, `name` and `keyword`

1. `string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)`
2. `string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword)`

Remaining checks would be simple:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    flatData  = flatData.Where(data => data.a.Name.Contains(name))
                        .Where(data => data.b.Name.Contains(name));

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
   flatData  = flatData.Where(data => data.c.Keyword.Contains(keyword));
```

**Important points:**

- `flatData` above has a cascading filter, first on `a.Name, b.Name and c.Keyword`