# How to use linq to "flatten" an hierachy?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following code example, how do I:

1. Get the commented out lines in the unfiltered list to work (without changing the definition of Result)?
2. Get the commented out lines in the filtered list to work (without changing the definition of Result)? From my maths it should give 32 records. Hopefully my output intent is clear enough for others to understand

Any questions feel free to ask

Regards

Kyle

```
    //Populate data
    var alphas = new List<Alpha>();
    
    for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)    
    {
       var alpha = new Alpha() { Id = a, Name = "A" + a };

       for (int b = 1; b <= 10; b++)
       {
         var beta = new Beta() { Id = b, Name = "B" + b };

         for (int c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
         {
            var charlie = new Charlie() { Id = c, Name = "C" + c };

            for (int d = 1; d <= 10; d++)
            {
                var delta = new Delta() { Id = d, Name = "D" + d };

                charlie.Deltas.Add(delta);
            }
            beta.Charlies.Add(charlie);
        }
        alpha.Betas.Add(beta);
       }    
      alphas.Add(alpha);
    }

//Get results into required format without filtering
var unfilteredResults = alphas.Select(a => new Result
{
    AId = a.Id,
    AName = a.Name,

    //BId = a.Betas.Select(b => b.Id),
    //BName = a.Betas.Select(b => b.Name),

    //CId = a.Betas.Select(b => b.Charlies.Select(c => c.Id)),
    //CName = a.Betas.Select(b => b.Charlies.Select(c => c.Name)),

    //DId = a.Betas.Select(b => b.Charlies.Select(c => c.Deltas.Select(d => d.Id))),
    //DName = a.Betas.Select(b => b.Charlies.Select(c => c.Deltas.Select(d => d.Name)))
});


var whiteListAIds = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
var whiteListBIds = new List<int>() { 3, 4 };
var whiteListCIds = new List<int>() { 5, 6 };
var whiteListDIds = new List<int>() { 7, 8 };

//Get results into required format with filtering
var filteredResults = alphas.Where(a => whiteListAIds.Contains(a.Id)).Select(a => new Result
{
    AId = a.Id,
    AName = a.Name,

    //BId = a.Betas.Where(b => whiteListBIds.Contains(b.Id)).Select(b => b.Id),
    //BName = a.Betas.Where(b => whiteListBIds.Contains(b.Id)).Select(b => b.Name),

    //CId = a.Betas.Where(b => whiteListBIds.Contains(b.Id)).Select(b => b.Charlies.Where(c => whiteListCIds.Contains(c.Id)).Select(c => c.Id)),
    //CName = a.Betas.Where(b => whiteListBIds.Contains(b.Id)).Select(b => b.Charlies.Where(c => whiteListCIds.Contains(c.Id)).Select(c => c.Name)),

    //DId = a.Betas.Where(b => whiteListBIds.Contains(b.Id)).Select(b => b.Charlies.Where(c => whiteListCIds.Contains(c.Id)).Select(c => c.Deltas.Where(d => whiteListDIds.Contains(d.Id)).Select(d => d.Id))),
    //DName = a.Betas.Where(b => whiteListBIds.Contains(b.Id)).Select(b => b.Charlies.Where(c => whiteListCIds.Contains(c.Id)).Select(c => c.Deltas.Where(d => whiteListDIds.Contains(d.Id)).Select(d => d.Name)))
});

class Alpha
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Beta> Betas { get; set; } = new List<Beta>();
}

class Beta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Charlie> Charlies { get; set; } = new List<Charlie>();
}

class Charlie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Delta> Deltas { get; set; } = new List<Delta>();
}

class Delta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Result
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string AName { get; set; }

    public int BId { get; set; }
    public string BName { get; set; }

    public int CId { get; set; }
    public string CName { get; set; }

    public int DId { get; set; }
    public string DName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: try selectMany()

Answer (score 0):

Got it working as below thanks to the first answer [linq selectmany flatten multiple levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222206/linq-selectmany-flatten-multiple-levels)

Basically had to combine .SelectMany() on the "outer" parents and .Select() on the last/inner child.

```
//Populate data
var alphas = new List<Alpha>();

for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
{
    var alpha = new Alpha() { Id = a, Name = "A" + a };

    for (int b = 1; b <= 10; b++)
    {
        var beta = new Beta() { Id = b, Name = "B" + b };

        for (int c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
        {
            var charlie = new Charlie() { Id = c, Name = "C" + c };

            for (int d = 1; d <= 10; d++)
            {
                var delta = new Delta() { Id = d, Name = "D" + d };

                charlie.Deltas.Add(delta);
            }
            beta.Charlies.Add(charlie);
        }
        alpha.Betas.Add(beta);
    }

    alphas.Add(alpha);
}   


var unfilteredResults = alphas.SelectMany(a => a.Betas.SelectMany(b=> b.Charlies.SelectMany(c=> c.Deltas.Select(d => new Result
{
    AId = a.Id,
    AName = a.Name,

    BId = b.Id,
    BName = b.Name,

    CId = c.Id,
    CName = c.Name,

    DId = d.Id,
    DName = d.Name
}))));


var whiteListAIds = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
var whiteListBIds = new List<int>() { 3, 4 };
var whiteListCIds = new List<int>() { 5, 6 };
var whiteListDIds = new List<int>() { 7, 8 };

//Get results into required format with filtering
var filteredResults = unfilteredResults.Where(r => whiteListAIds.Contains(r.AId) && whiteListBIds.Contains(r.BId) && whiteListCIds.Contains(r.CId) && whiteListDIds.Contains(r.DId));

Console.WriteLine("Finished");

class Alpha
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Beta> Betas { get; set; } = new List<Beta>();
}

class Beta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Charlie> Charlies { get; set; } = new List<Charlie>();
}

class Charlie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Delta> Deltas { get; set; } = new List<Delta>();
}

class Delta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Result
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string AName { get; set; }

    public int BId { get; set; }
    public string BName { get; set; }

    public int CId { get; set; }
    public string CName { get; set; }

    public int DId { get; set; }
    public string DName { get; set; }

}
```